Get font and size of a text
I have a pdf from which I want to get the font and size of each line because the information I want to extract has a different format. I'm trying to do this using c# with the iText7 library in UiPath, but I can't extract the font and size. Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!
string filePath = "x.pdf";
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument (new PdfReader(filePath));
for( int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); pageNum++)
{
 // ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
   LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
   string pageText = GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(pageNum), strategy);
   Console.WriteLine(pageText);

   IList<iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Data.TextRenderInfo> textRenderInfo =                    strategy.getResultantTextRenderInfos()();
foreach (iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Data.TextRenderInfo renderInfo in textRenderInfo)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(renderInfo.GetFont().GetFontProgram().GetFontNames().GetFontName);
}

but also getResultantTextRenderInfos() is no longer valid,

Does this answer your question? iText - Get Font size and family of a text segment AND/OR Getting form field font information in itext7  AND/OR Extract fontname, size, style from pdf with iText
